# How can I get MariaDB to use indexes in a RANK() query?

Tags: mysql, index, mariadb

Consider the following simple RANK() query.

```sql
select project_id, group_id, rank() 
  over (partition by group_id order by stars desc) as star_rank 
from project_metrics;
```

I've added indexes to the `project_metrics` table on `group_id`, `stars`, and `group_id, stars`.  And yet, MariaDB (server version 10.3.17) refuses to use any of the indexes.

```
> explain select project_id, group_id, rank() over (partition by group_id order by stars desc) as star_rank from project_metrics\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: project_metrics
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 55635183
        Extra: Using temporary
```

Am I missing something?

In response to comment by @Luuk, the JSON output of `explain` is as follows.
It may indicate that the required sorting is done efficiently after all (it uses two indexed keys for sorting). This would mean that the output of the plain `explain` is misleading.

```
EXPLAIN: {
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "window_functions_computation": {
      "sorts": {
        "filesort": {
          "sort_key": "project_metrics.group_id, project_metrics.stars desc"
        }
      },
      "temporary_table": {
        "table": {
          "table_name": "project_metrics",
          "access_type": "ALL",
          "rows": 55635465,
          "filtered": 100
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the cardinality of the fields in your query? Have/are you able to test this on any other MySQL fork?

Comment: What is output of `explain format=json select project_id, group_id, rank() over (partition by group_id order by stars desc) as star_rank from project_metrics;`   (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/explain-format-json/)

Comment: @Vérace select count(*) from (select distinct group_id from project_metrics) as a; gives 6392273 and the same for stars gives 7122. I haven't tested this on another fork.

Comment: @Luuk I amended the question with the JSON format output.

Comment: @DiomidisSpinellis: the explain.... gives `"filesort": {…` which indicates it is using the index on `group_id, stars`

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ No, I didn't think `project_id` would need to get indexed.

Comment: @Luuk, if you want, you can make that an answer.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ No, I didn't try it.